# Syntax error: Expected keyword SELECT but got end of script at [37:1] in Bigquery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have written give code

WITH lect lep_find as (
SELECT
admin_level_1,
tests_total,
tests_increase
FROM `bigquery-405008.about_covid_19_public_datasets.summary`
GROUP BY
date,admin_level_1, tests_total, tests_increase
LIMIT 1000
),

I want to retrieve information from the database where column name is admin_level_1, tests_total, tests_increase but its not working and getting Error below

(Syntax error: Expected keyword SELECT but got end of script at [37:1])

Comment: `WITH lep_find AS (
  SELECT
    admin_level_1,
    tests_total,
    tests_increase
  FROM
    your_dataset.your_table
    GROUP BY
    admin_level_1,
    tests_total,
    tests_increase
  LIMIT 1000
)
SELECT
  *
FROM
  lep_find;
`